# How do you define the options you see in ./configure --help?

Tags: gnu, autotools, configure

I'm currently trying to set up a package to be installed with autotools.

In most, if not all, major software packages, configure --help lists a large number of options like ./configure --ENABLE-FLOAT, etc. I was wondering where I can define these options.

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: The question is: what libraries or features are you requiring or including?

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684714/configuring-autoconf-to-have-with-options-to-customise-build

Answer (score 3):

Use [`AC_ARG_ENABLE`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/html_node/Package-Options.html) and [`AC_ARG_WITH`](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/html_node/External-Software.html) in your configure.ac file.