# configure.in and adding options

Tags: configure, autoconf

I am trying to add an option to my ./configure script. I need to add the location to mysql.h but a few methods I have tried and keep getting the error: configure: error: unrecognized option: --mysql=/usr/local/mysql/include/mysql/

How do I add the option to my configure script aswell as to add the header file which is specified.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you define the options you see in ./configure --help?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655177/how-do-you-define-the-options-you-see-in-configure-help)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably looking for [AC_ARG_WITH](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.60/html_node/External-Software.html). Something like this:

```
AC_ARG_WITH([mysql],
        [AS_HELP_STRING([--with-mysql=path : path to mysql headers])],
        [MYSQL_INCLUDE=$withval],
        [])
```

Then run `./configure --with-mysql=/foo` .

Comment: You also need to modify configure.in to do append MYSQL_INCLUDE to the CPP_FLAGS.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you are trying to get your compiler to include a specific include path when it builds. The easiest way to do that is with the CPPFLAGS environment variable, e.g.

```
% setenv CPPLAGS -I/usr/local/mysql/include/mysql/
% ./configure
% make
% etc...
```

If you actually need to add a new option to configure you'll need to learn about [autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/) and editing configure.in to generate a new configure script.

Comment: I am using autoconf and already have a configure.in script that looks for mysql.h, i just dont know how to specify a custom location for mysql.h in configure.in using options

Comment: You should be able to set the CPPFLAGS environment variable as I show in my answer (I originally said CFLAGS, but CPPFLAGS is more correct).

Or do you actually need a configure argument?